# Programmatically scroll to an Anchor Tag

Tags: asp.net, navigation, anchor

Consider the following code:

```
<a href="#label2">GoTo Label2</a>
... [content here] ...
<a name="label0"></a>More content
<a name="label1"></a>More content
<a name="label2"></a>More content
<a name="label3"></a>More content
<a name="label4"></a>More content
```

Is there a way to emulate clicking on the "GoTo Label2" link to scroll to the appropriate region on the page through code?

**EDIT**: An acceptable alternative would be to scroll to an element with a unique-id, which already exists on my page.  I would be adding the anchor tags if this is a viable solution.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666038/asp-net-postback-scroll-to-specific-position

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This JS has generally worked well for me if you also put an ID on the element:

```
document.getElementById('MyID').scrollIntoView(true);
```

This is good as it will also position scrollable divs etc so that the content is visible.

Answer (score 11):

Using javascript:

```
window.location.href = '#label2';
```

If you need to do it from the server/code behind, you can just emit this Javascript and register it as a startup script for that page.

Comment: This worked great for me, could still use an anchor. Webbrower control embedded in a winforms app.

Answer (score 3):

Moving to a anchor from server side, example is c#.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#form';", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this will work:

```
window.location="<yourCurrentUri>#label2";
```

Answer (score 1):

If the element is an anchor tag, you should be able to do:

```
document.getElementsByName('label2')[0].focus();
```

Comment: You have mistake in your code - it is document.getElementsByName. Source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816863/how-to-use-document-getelementbyname-and-getelementbytag

Answer (score 1):

The solution

```
document.getElementById('MyID').scrollIntoView(true);
```

works well in almost all browsers, whereas I've noticed that in some browsers or in some mobile (such as some Blackberry versions) "scrollIntoView" function is not recognized, so I would consider this solution (a bit uglier than the previous one):

```
window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + 
                       window.location.pathname + window.location.search + 
                       "#MyAnchor";
```

Answer (score 0):

no "#" when you use window.location.hash

Answer (score -1):

you can just open the new URL with the name appended, for instance `http://www.example.com/mypage.htm#label2`

In JavaScript,

```
location.href = location.href + '#label2';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break if you execute it more than once?

http://www.mysite.com/mypage.htm#label2#label2