# Go to specific line number on a page using # but not in url

Tags: html, visual-studio-2005, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a record set with hundreds of rows. when a user clicks the row they go somewhere else and later get redirected to the page with the rows again. I want the page to start on the exact row the clicked on.

I have rows set up with a line number corresponding to each record number from the database.

```
//some record set

while not RS.eof

<a name="<%=line%>">
//other stuff

Rs.movenext
   Line = line + 1
wend
```

when you put '#' in the url and a number it goes to the line number. However, my issue is that the url is off limits. I have the line number stored as a Session variable that happens after they initially leave the page. How can i get the page to go to the line number using the session variable and not the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, anchor names are a feature of the browser. But there are possibly some Javascript libraries that can scroll down to an anchor name without needing the url.

[Here's an SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265774/programmatically-scroll-to-an-anchor-tag) on how to programatically scroll down to a certain location.

I think this works also but I haven't tested it

```
window.location.hash = "#anchorname";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't do anything with the URL, your best (only) bet is JavaScript on the client.

```
function scrollTo(row) {
  window.location.hash = "#" + row;
}
```

And call that in `body.onload`, for example. Put the value of your session variable into the function call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need anchors for this.  You can capture the scroll position as a post a request variable and set it back with JavaScript in the page load.

The second option in the post is not specific to asp.net.
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140248/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111704-1.aspx

Comment: Scroll position is kinda useless if the page itself changes, yet the specific position should still be targeted. Other than that, nice trick. +1