# hyperlink question (anchors?)

Tags: hyperlink

How can I make the data (Req#Approved or Req#Reject) to be hyperlink so when I click it will drill down details below.

```
empnum  Req#Approved    Req#Reject
123         2   
123                     3
```

10-q ;)

Comment: I would like to turn the data as hyperlink so when I click it will drill down to details.  Is that clear?

Comment: instead of using the SELECT (command) link, I would rather use the data.  I hope I explained that well otherwise let me know.

Comment: Drill Down? As in you will go to a new page that has that detail? or as in the detail is on the page... and you need to scroll to that area?

Comment: correct - the detail is on the same page.

Comment: Thanks BigBlondeViking, you've found that this is a **duplicate** of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265774/programmatically-scroll-to-an-anchor-tag. Let's close it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

[Programmatically scroll to an Anchor Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265774/programmatically-scroll-to-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: Thanks BigBlondeViking - this will be a big help for me.  :)