# ReturnUrl and preserve scroll position?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

How do I indicate position on page in returnUrl?

```
  returnUrl= HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include some type of a tag in the url and then have some javascript that runs to scroll to the right section based on the tag you have supplied.

StackOverflow does it based on the postid passed in with the url.  StackOverflow includes a #1234567 at the end of the url and then auto scrolls the tag's anchor in a section.

You should refer to the following question to see how to implement the scrolling to an anchor:

[Programmatically scroll to an Anchor Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265774/programmatically-scroll-to-an-anchor-tag)