# ASP.net Postback - Scroll to Specific Position

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, webforms

I have an ASP.net WebForms page that has a lot of content on the top of the screen. It has a link button that will post back to the page and show another section of the page. When the page refreshes, I would like to set focus and scroll down to this section of the page.

I tried doing

```
txtField.Focus()
```

in my code behind and it will set focus and try to scroll there, but then scrolls right back to the top. The focus is still on my text box but the position of the screen is at the very top. The Link is at the top of the screen which is causing the postback. I want to scroll to the very bottom of the screen. It does this briefly and then scrolls right back to the top.

I have tried setting

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = false;
```

but that doesn't seem to help either.

Is there some way I can force it to go to a specific position?
Is it possible to add an anchor tag to the URL when I postback using a button or link button?

Comment: No. The link is at the top of the screen. I want to scroll to the bottom of the screen. When I postback it does this briefly because I am calling the Focus() method on the control, but then for some reason the it will scroll right back to the top.

Comment: Use client side script to set focus. That will also take care of scrolling to control.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either. It's like there is something on my page that is causing it to scroll to the top every time. Can't figure it out. Is it possible to add an anchor tag to my URL when I post back?

Comment: The scroll control in asp.net web forms is broken and does not work.  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback is part of this defective system.  You need to either set the scroll yourself clientside, wth enough delay to avoid race conditions... or override Microsoft's ScriptResource code.  I finally decided that overriding their WebForm_AutoFocus function was the only way to make the page not jump around.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Maintain-Scroll-Position-After-Postback-in-ASP-NET-WebForms

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;` should take you back to the same position on the screen, but you could use AJAX, or you could use `SetFocus()` to focus on a specific control after the postback:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx

Comment: What about using an id attribute (anchor tag) for different sections of the page? You could dynamically populate Response.Redirect("yourpagewithanchortagrefernece") after the postback

Comment: Ended up just using an UpdatePanel, as much as I hate them :(

Comment: It didn't work for me, look at the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(..) solution below that worked for me

Comment: Yes, Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack *should* do that... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the code below if you have an anchor for the location:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#MOVEHERE';", true);
```

Comment: @Dismissile This should be marked as the answer, in my opinion.  You do not have to reload the page from scratch (so the code can be applied only when certain post back events occur), plus the the answer that was accepted was not used and was stated to be the exact opposite of what was asked for.

Comment: This worked for me, with setting
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;
in the particular instance (since my page has that set true, generally)

Comment: This is probably going to encounter race conditions.

Answer (score 9):

In your case I suggest you to keep the default value of Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack, and use the pure javascript scrolling function

```
function scrollToDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('yourDiv').scrollIntoView();
}
```

And call it at the page startup with a little delay of 1ms (pure javascript again)

```
setTimeout(scrollToDiv, 1);
```

And finally call it from the C# code behind, with the RegisterStartupScript (js executed after all the page has been loaded) :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ScrollToADiv", "setTimeout(scrollToDiv, 1);", true);
```

Like this, it will bypass any asp automatic scrolling

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack) {
            string targetId = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "focusthis", "document.getElementById('" + targetId + "').focus()", true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21979164)

Answer (score 0):

`Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true`  seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried  [Matthieu Charbonnier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657800/52277), but it didn't work unless I've added

```
" window.scrollTo = function () { };"
```

as it was suggested in http://gnidesign.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-on-postback.html

I've created a helper method, that's working in Chrome,FireFox and IE

```
public static void ScrollToControl( Page page, string clientId, bool alignToTop)
 {
     //NOTE: if there are more than one call on the page, first one will take preference
     //If we want that last will take  preference, change key from MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name to anchorName
     //recommended in http://gnidesign.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-on-postback.html              
     String script = " window.scrollTo = function () { };" + Environment.NewLine;
     script += String.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').scrollIntoView({1});" , clientId, alignToTop.JSToString());
     page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(TypeForClientScript(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, script, true );
     //return script;
 }
 public static string JSToString(this bool bValue)
 {
     return bValue.ToString().ToLower();
 }
```

Use getElementById('{0}').scrollIntoView is simpler than location.hash , because you don't need to add extra anchor element.

Parameter alignToTop is very convenient to specify do you want to show control at the top or bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
<asp:MultiView ID="mvAriza" runat="server">
      <asp:View ID="View14" runat="server"> 
         ............ .......
      </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

on *.aspx page. And on the *.aspx.cs page on a button click.

```
Page.SetFocus(mvAriza.ClientID);
```

It works great.

Answer (score 0):

This scroll automatically to desired Div in asp.net Control
This is Function
call it from Where you Want 
and also Download Java script file

OnClientClick="return scrollGrid()"

function scrollGrid1() {
                $('html,body').animate
                    (
                    {
                        scrollTop: $('#Div1').offset().top
                    },
                    'slow'
                    )
        }

Answer (score 0):

While not elegant for your situation, it is also possible to use dummy Custom Validators, set the one you want to scroll to as invalid then do

```
DummyCustomValidator.SetFocusOnError = true;
```

In my case, I am actually using page Validators with async postbacks and multiple programmatically shown/hidden panels on a long vertical form. Since some fields are only required if MyLogicalParent.Visible = true and if specific answers are given in other controls, such as a RequiredFieldValidator on a TextBox when "Other" is selected in a CheckBoxList, I have a LOT of logic to process page validation. Setting scroll positions was painful in all of the normal methods.

I also use RegisterStartupScript to handle maintaining the current scroll position when async postbacks alter the page's vertical dimension.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var windowHeight = $(document)[0].documentElement.clientHeight;    /*This is the height of the viewable browser area.*/
            var scrolledPosition = $(window)[0].scrollY;                       /*This is the number of Pixels the Window is currently scrolled to.*/
            var scroll = windowHeight + scrolledPosition;                       /*This should be the same as $(window).scrollTop() */
            /*If the amount scrolled + the height of the window is Less than or equal to the total height of the page (past the viewable client window)*/
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + getWindowSize()[1] <= getDocHeight()) {
                /*Move the morescroll div to the bottom of the page... -34 is the height of the div plus a small bottom margin.*/
                $("#morescroll").offset({ top: windowHeight - 34 });
            }
        })

        /*This is the total height of the document including the area past the viewable client window.*/
        function getDocHeight() {
            var D = document;
            /*The Largest of these six numbers is the total doc height. */
            return Math.max(
                D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
                D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
            );
        }

        /*This is the width and height of the Viewable Browser area.*/
        function getWindowSize() {
            var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
            if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
                //Non-IE
                myWidth = window.innerWidth;
                myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
                myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
                //IE 4 compatible
                myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
            }
            return [myWidth, myHeight];
        }

        //This sets a transparent div <div id="morescroll" class="scrollMinder"> with the text "Scroll down for more." to the bottom of the viewable page. 
        $(window).scroll(
            function () {
                var windowHeight = $(document)[0].documentElement.clientHeight;
                var scrolledPosition = $(window)[0].scrollY;
                var scrll = windowHeight + scrolledPosition;
                document.getElementById('<%= HF_LastScrolled.ClientID %>').value = scrolledPosition;
                var docHeight = $(document)[0].documentElement.scrollHeight;
                /*if we are scrolled to within 60 pixels from the bottom of the document, hide the indicator so it doesn't cover the footer.*/
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 60) {
                    $("#morescroll").hide();
                }
                /*if we scroll back above 60 pixels from the bottom of the document, show the indicator and set the top of the div to -34 pixels.*/
                else if ($(window).scrollTop() + getWindowSize()[1] <= getDocHeight()) {
                    $("#morescroll").show();
                    $("#morescroll").offset({ top: scrll - 34 });
                }
            });
</script>

     <%-- This stores the Y scroll location.--%>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HF_LastScrolled" runat="server" />
        <div id="morescroll" class="scrollMinder">
            <span class="spanMinder">Scroll down for more.</span>
        </div>





 private string LastScrolled = "";

    protected void Page_PreRender (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastScrolled))
                {
                    LastScrolled = "0";
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scrollPosition))
                {
                    sb.Clear();
                    sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                    sb.AppendLine("function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {");
                    sb.Append("scrollTo(0, ").Append(LastScrolled).Append(");");
                    sb.AppendLine("}");
                    sb.AppendLine("function load() {");
                    sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                    sb.AppendLine("}");
                    cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollToLastPosition", sb.ToString(), true);
                    scrollPosition = "ScrollToLastPosition";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scrollPosition))
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), scrollPosition, sb.ToString(), true);
                }
            }

    protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              LastScrolled = HF_LastScrolled.Value;
              Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;
            }

   protected void SetScrollToLastPosition ()
            {
                sb.Clear();
                sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                sb.AppendLine("function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {");
                sb.Append("scrollTo(0, ").Append(LastScrolled).AppendLine(");");
                sb.AppendLine("}");
                sb.AppendLine("function load() {");
                sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                sb.AppendLine("}");
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollToLastPosition", sb.ToString(), true);
                scrollPosition = "ScrollToLastPosition";
                string tempstring = sb.ToString();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), scrollPosition, sb.ToString(), true);
            }

protected void SetScrolltoPositionY (int y)
            {
                sb.Clear();
                sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                sb.AppendLine("function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {");
                sb.Append("scrollTo(0, ").Append(y).AppendLine(");");
                sb.AppendLine("}");
                sb.AppendLine("function load() {");
                sb.AppendLine("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);");
                sb.AppendLine("}");
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScrollTo-0-" + y.ToString(), sb.ToString(), true);
                scrollPosition = "ScrollTo - 0-" + y.ToString();
                string tempstring = sb.ToString();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), scrollPosition, sb.ToString(), true);
            }
```