# How to scroll GridView without AJAX or jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, scroll

I am using an ASP GridView. Each row has a unique ID like this: `<tr id="abc123">`

When this page is visited, I may get the ID from session or query string in `Page_Load()`. If I find the ID, I need to scroll to the specific row.

I cannot use AJAX or jQuery because it is a legacy application. There are few solutions I have found but they are depending on jQuery/AJAX/Bootstrap etc. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666109/1050256) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265880/1050256). This is not a postback, so I cannot use `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`.

Comment: Have you considered using a [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) like `https://www.example.com/thispage#abc123`?

Comment: Is JavaScript allowed? [ScrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is supported in all browsers nowadays and you could render the relevant script at the end of the page.

Comment: @AndrewMorton My URL is coming like `https://www.example.com/thispage.aspx?SomeID=abc123` I can change it to what you are suggesting. The issue is on the page when trying to take the scroll action. I am retrieving SomeID in `Page_Load()`.

Comment: Which means you could also emit some JavaScript to call {element}.scrollIntoView()  - @AndrewMorton has the right idea