# Load page with Target in URI when returning from Postback

Tags: .net, postback, target

I have multiple segments on a web page, identified with targets, like this:

```
<div id="target1" class="section">
          <h4><a href="#target1">Buildings by Name</a></h4>
          <div>

              // button to call server side function
          </div>
</div>
```

So when user clicks "Buildings by Name", the URI changes to
http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx#target1

i need to call a server side function, which will do some processing.  And when i return from the server side script, i want to reload the page with the same targeted URI
http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx#target1 .  Right now, when I return from the postback, the URI is just /page.aspx

is there a way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.  Not the most glamorous, but it seems to work.  I used this post as a guide:
[Programmatically scroll to an Anchor Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265774/programmatically-scroll-to-an-anchor-tag)

So, in the server side code, after processing, I called a javascript function:
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scrolling",
      "scrollToResults()");

Then, in the aspx page, i threw in the javascrpt function:

```
<Script>
function scrollToResults() {
         // next 2 lines work on desktop browsers, but not mobile
         // var el = document.getElementById("target1");
         // el.scrollIntoView(true);

         // this bit will work for most mobile browsers
            window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +
                   window.location.pathname + window.location.search +
                   "#target1";
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go down the AJAX route with this. Basically, use JavaScript to override the click handler on your  tag, run a call to the server, and populate the data from the response into your .

I'm a fan of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for these tasks, but there's a slew of great tools out there to help.

And some tutorials on doing AJAX w/ jQuery:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Comment: Thanks - yes, Ajax is great.  I'm developing this for a mobile site.  i'm not sure how broad the jquery support is for mobile devices...will have to investigate some.