# Validation form using Javascript, seem to be missing a little code or perhaps a little understanding

Tags: javascript, validation

So here's what I have so far.  What I'd like my code to render is that if any of the three user inputs are invalid, the corresponding error message should be displayed on screen.

As it is at the moment, this does not happen....also what I thought would be a nice touch is that once the correct input has been typed, that it would then display a green tick mark after the input field, alas I have been unable to implement this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

        <title>Validation</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--

            function validate_form() {
                valid = true;

                if (document.contact_form.pin.value == "") {
                    alert("Please fill in your '4 Digit PIN' in the box.");
                    valid = false;
                } else if (document.contact_form.pin.value == "1234") {
                    content: "✓";
                    color: green;
                }

                if (document.contact_form.surname.value == "") {
                    alert("Please complete your surname");
                    valid = false;
                } else if (document.contact_form.surname.value == "Doe") {
                    content: "✓";
                    color: green;
                }

                if (document.contact_form.email.value == "") {
                    alert("Icorrect email address for current user");
                    valid = false;
                } else if (document.contact_form.email.value == "doe09@gmail.com") {
                    content: "✓";
                    color: green;
                }




                return valid;
            }

            //-->
        </script>

    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="http://www.dcu.ie/" onSubmit="return validate_form ( );">

            <h1>John Doe (C1_A2_2015)</h1>
            <p>4 Digit PIN:
                <input type="text" name="pin">
            </p>
            <p>Surname:
                <input type="text" name="surname">
                <p>E-mail:
                    <input type="text" name="email">



                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Validate Inputs">
                    </p>

        </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: @Teemu: Actually, those statements are syntactically legal and will not produce any errors.  (they are meaningless and have no effect, though)

Comment: @SLaks You're right, they are labels with a following expression. I've removed my comment.

Comment: You're confusing Javascript and CSS.  You need to learn how to manipulate the DOM, and handle keyboard events.

Comment: I understand the syntax is more or less correct, but at the moment if the email address is correct and the other two fields are incorrect....regardless of this the form will validate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can achieve it like this.

```
 var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
 if (form.elements.namedItem("pin").value === "") {
                alert("Please fill in your '4 Digit PIN' in the box.");
                valid = false;
            } else if (form.elements.namedItem("pin").value === "1234") {
                content: "✓";
                color: green;
            }
```

Do the same for the rest of the conditions. As suggested in the comments, the javascript code you have written has no effect as the syntax is not write.

you can check [How to use document.getElementByName and getElementByTag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816863/how-to-use-document-getelementbyname-and-getelementbytag) to know more about getting elements by name and by ID.

2) For your `onSubmit` function, you do not need to add `;` .

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="http://www.dcu.ie/" onSubmit="return validate_form()">
```

check this tutorial for more details. http://www.formget.com/javascript-onsubmit/

3) Please note, I have used `===` instead of `==`. In your case it should not make any difference. However just for information,  `===` matches object type and value both. `==` matches only value. So if you want to be sure that the two objects you are matching are of same type and value, then use `===` otherwise `==`. Some IDE's give warning if you use `==`.

4) Your form is getting validated as you are entering something in the text fields. You have a check for text fields to be empty and text fields to have correct text. But you do not have anything that check for incorrect input. Just do not add anything and hit submit button. Your validate function should work

Modify your code like this

```
if (form.elements.namedItem("pin").value === "" || form.elements.namedItem("pin").value != "1234") {
                alert("Please fill in your '4 Digit PIN' in the box.");
                valid = false;
            }
```

Here is the working code. I have made some changes in your code and have commented them for your reference.

The code is not working on JSFiddle which I do not know why. However I have tested it in Chrome and firefox and works fine. Hope this will solve your issue. :)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Validation</title>

 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function validate_form() {
        var valid = true; //defined valid

        var myform = document.getElementById("myFormID");   //define myForm variable only once and added ID to your HTML form
        if (myform.elements.namedItem("pin").value === "" || myform.elements.namedItem("pin").value != "1234") {
            alert("Please fill in your '4 Digit PIN' in the box.");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (myform.elements.namedItem("surname").value === "" || myform.elements.namedItem("surname").value != "Doe") {
            alert("Please enter the correct Surname.");
            valid = false;
        }

        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");

            valid = false;    //do not return false here
        }

        //alert(valid);
        return valid; //return valid at the end which is intialised as true.
    }
 </script>
 </head>    
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<form name="myForm" id="myFormID" action="http://www.dcu.ie/" onSubmit="return validate_form()" method="post">

    <h1> John Doe (C1_A2_2015) </h1>
    <p>4 Digit PIN:
        <input type="text" name="pin">
    </p>

    <p>Surname:
        <input type="text" name="surname">
    </p>
     <p>E-mail:
            <input type="text" name="email">
     </p>

      <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Validate Inputs">
      </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this still does not solve my issue...I've scrapped the idea of the green ticks now as it's surplus to requirements.  My main requirement is that if any of the input fields are not 100% correct, then the form should not validate...as the code is if I put 123 in all 3 fields, the form will still validate as being true

Comment: Your form is getting validated as you are entering something in the text fields. You have a check for text fields to be empty and text fields to have correct text. But you do not have anything that check for incorrect input. Just donot add anything and hit submit button. Your validate function should work

Comment: Your suggestions make my code look cleaner, maybe what I'm looking to do is not actually possible.
1. I want the text boxes only to accept exactly what I have specified
2. If any of the 3 are incorrect, there should be an alert box stating so
3. If and only if all 3 are correct, should the form then validate.

Here is my modified code, based upon your suggestions..and thank you for your time and help so far, I appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdkmY/292/

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!!!
I'll be sure to study this and understand my shortcomings and learn from your help.