# adding click events to divs to change hidden input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get two divs to act as checkboxes (so that users can select 0 or all) that will influence hidden input values for a total that starts at 0. I am targetting the clicked divs by toggling a bootstrap color class to show user which has been chosen and - based on that class - add values to the hidden total input values below. I can get the totals to change outright, but I am trying to add to and subtract from the totals based on what is clicked/unclicked. Right now my code is returning an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null". Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select-class').on('click', function() {
    //toggle clicked divs to show what's been selected
    $(this).toggleClass('color');
    //add values to total(0) if divs are clicked (have color class)
    if (this.classList.contains('color')) {
      //add1:
      var addTotal1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total1').value);
      var addSingle1 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add1').value);
      addTotal1 += addSingle1;
      document.getElementById('totaladd1').value = addTotal1.toString();
      //add2:
      var addTotal2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total2').value);
      var addSingle2 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add2').value);
      addTotal2 += addSingle2;
      document.getElementById('totaladd2').value = addTotal2.toString();
      //add3:
      var addTotal3 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total3').value);
      var addSingle3 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add3').value);
      addTotal3 += addSingle3;
      document.getElementById('totaladd3').value = addTotal3.toString();
    }
    //Subtract values if divs are unclicked (don't have color class)
    if (!this.classList.contains('color')) {
      //add1:
      var addTotal1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total1').value);
      var addSingle1 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add1').value);
      addTotal1 -= addSingle1;
      document.getElementById('totaladd1').value = addTotal1.toString();
      //add2:
      var addTotal2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total2').value);
      var addSingle2 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add2').value);
      addTotal2 -= addSingle2;
      document.getElementById('totaladd2').value = addTotal2.toString();
      //add3:
      var addTotal3 = Number(document.getElementsByName('total3').value);
      var addSingle3 = Number(document.getElementById(this.id.toString() + 'add3').value);
      addTotal3 -= addSingle3;
      document.getElementById('totaladd3').value = addTotal3.toString();
    }


  })
});
```

```html
<div class="row p-lg-5">
  <div id="div1" class="select-class">
    <p>Content</p>
    <!--hidden values-->
    <div class="d-none">
      <input type="number" class="add1" id="div1add1" value="1" />
      <input type="number" class="add2" id="div1add2" value="45" />
      <input type="number" class="add3" id="div1add3" value="4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="select-class">
    <p>Content</p>
    <!--hidden values-->
    <div class="d-none">
      <input type="number" class="add1" id="div2add1" value="3" />
      <input type="number" class="add2" id="div2add2" value="20" />
      <input type="number" class="add3" id="div2add3" value="3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--hidden totals-->
<div class="d-none">
  <input id="totaladd1" type="number" name="total1" value="0" />
  <input id="totaladd2" type="number" name="total2" value="0" />
  <input id="totaladd3" type="number" name="total3" value="0" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816863/how-to-use-document-getelementbyname-and-getelementbytag/7816899

Comment: Questions should include the minimum code needed to demonstrate the problem; the code you've provided is clearly not all needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Set your *add* inputs as `disabled` by default
- Add a `data-total=""` to every *total* input. Inside the data place the add-inputs-pairs selector i.e: `".add_1"` etc...
- Toggle class on click and perform a search for the non `disabled` *add* inputs, reducing their values to an accumulated number. Set that number as the iterating *total* input value

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  function calculateTot() {
    $('[data-total]').each(function() {
      const pair = $(this.dataset.total).not(':disabled').get();
      $(this).val(pair.reduce((n, el) => (n += +el.value, n), 0))
    });
  }

  $('.select-class').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-selected');
    $(this).find('input').prop('disabled', !$(this).is('.is-selected'));
    calculateTot();
  }).find('input').prop('disabled', true); // Make inputs disabled by default
  
  calculateTot(); // Calculate also on DOM ready
  
});
```

```css
.select-class {cursor:pointer; padding:8px; border-radius:1em; border:1px solid #000;}
.is-selected {background:#0bf;}
.d-none {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="row p-lg-5">
  <div id="div1" class="select-class">
    Content 1 - Select me
    <div class="d-none">
      <input type="number" class="add_1" value="1" />
      <input type="number" class="add_2" value="45" />
      <input type="number" class="add_3" value="4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="select-class">
    Content 2 - Select me
    <div class="d-none">
      <input type="number" class="add_1" value="3" />
      <input type="number" class="add_2" value="20" />
      <input type="number" class="add_3" value="3" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div> <!-- class="d-none" -->
  <input data-total=".add_1" type="number" name="total1" />
  <input data-total=".add_2" type="number" name="total2" />
  <input data-total=".add_3" type="number" name="total3" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked like a charm. I really need to practice arrow functions!