# Javascript for loop getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fill in the second column with value **50** when the CheckBox is checked and with value **0** when the CheckBox is unchecked.
I seems that `document.getElementsByName("val" + i).value` doesn't work properly or I missed something.

[image]

**EDIT** I replaced  `document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0].value` with `document.getElementsByName("val" + i).value` and I introduce `if` condition inside the loop

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var i;

  
    for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        if (checkBox.checked == true) {
            document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0].value  = "50";
        } else {
            document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0].value  = "0";
        }
    }
  
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Interval</th>
    <th>Valori</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Int 1</td>
    <td><input name="val1" value size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Int 2</td>
    <td><input name="val2" value size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Int 3</td>
    <td><input name="val3" value size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Int 4</td>
    <td><input name="val4" value size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Int 5</td>
    <td><input name="val5" value size="5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: firstly, your `if` statement should either be inside your for loop, or you should have a for loop on your else

Comment: See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName "The getElementsByName() method of the Document object returns a **NodeList Collection** of elements with a given name in the document."

Comment: @PM77-1 - your else refers to the variable `i`  incremented by the for loop in a different scope, so this will have the value of 0 or table.rows.length-1 in the else block

Comment: @developer - yes, your `or` part is relevant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816863/how-to-use-document-getelementbyname-and-getelementbytag

Comment: @developer Your're right and I've done this but still doesn't work

Comment: because secondly, elements can have same name so when you get them by name you get a collection.  use an id instead, and get by id

Comment: @developer In my project this is how is done with `name` without `id`

Comment: you can have an `id` too,  `name` attr is primarily for the post back.   but if you just want to use `name` - then you should unwrap the collection like this: `document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0]` to unwrap, but this will only work if you have just one element with that name

Comment: This works: `getElementsByName("val1")[0].value` but when I put in for loop it doesn't work anymore when I change `1` with `+i`

Comment: im not sure of you latest code,  so ill post an answer if you think it will help - or update your question??

Comment: note that in: `getElementsByName("val" + i)[0]`  the index inside `[0]` shouldn't be `i` it should be a `0` always, but your `"val" + i` is correct, it should use i

Comment: @developer Indeed this was the problem. Thank you !

Comment: glad it's working - I wasnt able to post an answer as it was marked as duplicate - not sure how `@Always Sunny` did - must be a reputation thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. You have several issues with your current code.

1. You've 6 elements on your table including the first **tr** `<tr>th>Interval</th><th>Valori</th></tr>` so you need to start from `i = 1;` not `i = 0;`
2. `document.getElementsByName` returns a **NodeList** of elements. And a NodeList of elements does not have a `.value` property. So you've to use the index `[0]` before accessing it.
3. As you said you want **zero** when it is not checked so you need `window.onload = myFunction;`, it will help you to set initially all the column as **zero** value.
4. Slightly modify your `checkBox.checked` condition so you can set **50** on the check and **0** on uncheck.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0].value = 50;
    } else {
      document.getElementsByName("val" + i)[0].value = 0;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = myFunction;
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onchange="myFunction()">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Interval</th>
      <th>Valori</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Int 1</td>
      <td><input name="val1" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Int 2</td>
      <td><input name="val2" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Int 3</td>
      <td><input name="val3" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Int 4</td>
      <td><input name="val4" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Int 5</td>
      <td><input name="val5" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>




</body>

</html>
```